# AngularJs: NumberOnly directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to allow numbers only and - sign in textbox.
When i type - sign on IPhone safari it remove value from input like a backspace.
But it is working fine on android and IPad safari.
Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('numberOnly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
            var pattern = /[^0-9]/g;
            var digitsLength = attrs.digitsLength || 0;
            var allowMinus = attrs.allowMinus || false;

            if (allowMinus) {
                pattern = /(?!^-)[^0-9]/g;
            } else {
                pattern = /[^0-9]/g;
            }

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {

                if (newValue) {
                    var result = newValue.toString().replace(pattern, '');
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(result);

                    if (digitsLength > 0) {
                        if (result.charAt(0) === '-') {
                            if (result.substring(1, result.length).length > digitsLength) {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (result.substring(0, result.length).length > digitsLength) {
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                ngModel.$render();
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

app.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" number-only digits-length="7" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below custom directive which I've used. You can modify the regex here to filter the text.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" replacewith="[^0-9-]" ng-model="number">

app.directive('replacewith',replacewith);
replacewith.$inject = ['$timeout'];
function replacewith($timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      regex: '@replacewith'

    }, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
      model.$parsers.push(function(val) {
          if (!val) { 
                $timeout(function(){
                    model.$setValidity('parse', true);
                }, 0);
                return; 
            }
        var regex = new RegExp(scope.regex);
        var replaced = val.replace(regex, ''); 
        if (replaced !== val) {
          model.$setViewValue(replaced);
          model.$render();
        }         
        return replaced;         
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a lot more easier if you use

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value">
```

and check validity of the input. Also you can set digits length by setting min and max values of the input.

```
  $scope.example = {
    max: 9999999,
    min: 1000000
  };
```

with the following min max settings only 7 digits numbers will be valid.

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
       min="{{example.min}}" max="{{example.max}}">
```